TMC2208 Circuit diagram
I have a question about design pcb based on tmc2208 ic I have follow
github SilentStepStick
Why En pin is linked to 5v vcc with 20k resistor on the circuit diagram and manual say that it have to be grounded to enable the motor if i have understand... .
I don't understand the datasheet about ENN

thanks in advance

As noted in the bottom left (when correctly oriented) of the schematic, the 20k resistor is a pullup resistor. It is meant to disable the driver by default, when the EN pin is otherwise left floating. Pin 8 on the JP1 connector is labeled EN, therefore you can control the EN pin via a GPIO p>- or other control method - on that pin.So applying a logic LOW voltage to Pin 8 of JP1 will enable the driver, applying a logic HIGH voltage will disable the driver, and leaving it unconnected/floating will disable the driver.

So if i understand well if i pull the EN pin to ground or connect to a gpio to low i enable the motor ?

@KhalesNaim yes, your understanding is correct.
